# Plotting using plotyy

Tags: matlab, multiple-axes

Currently using this code to plot three sets of data.  y2 and y3 should be on the 800ish y-axis, y1 should be along the 0.25ish axis.

```
x=aEn;
y1=dedxAir;
y2=dedxGold;
y3=dedxU;
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x,y1,[x',x'],[y2',y3'])
```

However, this produces the following plot.

Hope the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxXnN.jpg) works...There shouldn't be four graphs - only three.  Part of my problem is I don't fully understand the syntax (taken straight from the documentation).   Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: what programming language is this?

Comment: @Samer  I'm using matlab.